# How do I align each text mark in a layered stacked bar charts?

Tags: vega-lite

[image]

I tried adjusting the encoding for each text mark with the color encoding or the x encoding, but could never get the label to be in the correct segment. I must have misunderstood some encoding due to the unconventional layer I am trying to achieve.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "sentiment", "equal": "negative"}}],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "type", "title": null, "axis": null},
        "x": {
          "field": "sentiment",
          "aggregate": "count",
          "axis": null,
          "sort": "descending"
        },
        "color": {"field": "channel"}
      },
      "layer": [
        {"mark": "bar"},
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "fill": "white"},
          "encoding": {"text": {"field": "sentiment", "aggregate": "count"}}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": 20,
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "center", "fontWeight": 400},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "type", "axis": null},
        "text": {"field": "type"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "sentiment", "equal": "positive"}}],
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"field": "channel"},
        "y": {"field": "type", "axis": null},
        "x": {"field": "sentiment", "aggregate": "count", "axis": null}
      },
      "layer": [
        {"mark": "bar"},
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "fill": "white"},
          "encoding": {"text": {"field": "sentiment", "aggregate": "count"}}
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": null}, "axis": {"grid": false}},
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"id": 1, "type": "shops", "channel": "line man", "sentiment": "negative"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. All I had to do was add a stack property with the value of zero to the x encoding for both bar charts.